# Kotlin: How to call a method with the same name in an extension?

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

I have written a `startsWith(substring)` extension that is applicable to nullable strings too. Unfortunatly my implmentation results in a StackOverflowError cause the extension calls it self an not the `String.startsWith(..)` method.

```
private fun String?.startsWith(sub: String): Boolean = this?.startsWith(sub)==true
```

Is is possible to call `String.startsWith(..)`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`import as`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#imports) syntax to explicitly import the standard library's `startsWith` method with a different name that you can then use without conflict:

```
import kotlin.text.startsWith as ktStartsWith

private fun String?.startsWith(sub: String): Boolean = this?.ktStartsWith(sub) == true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
private fun String?.startsWith(sub: String): Boolean = this?.startsWith(sub, false) == true
```

which uses this signature of `startsWith` from `StringsJVM.kt`:

```
public fun String.startsWith(prefix: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean
```

This way, by explicitly passing a value to the `ignoreCase` parameter, 
you avoid recursion because your extension function does not call itself anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the null check first, then call `startsWith` to the non-null `String`. Here is an example using `run`:

```
private fun String?.startsWith(sub: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean = this?.run{startsWith(sub, ignoreCase)} ?: false
```

Within the block `this?.run{ /* this is non-null inside here */}`. Therefore, calling `startsWith` inside will not call your own extension method.